# GHC error for missing strict fields

Tags: haskell, strictness

I'm reading [this article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/09/all-about-strictness#strict-data). It reads:

> When constructing a value with record syntax, GHC will give you an error if you forget a strict field. It will only give you a warning for non-strict fields.

Can anyone give me a concrete example of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A trivial example:

```
GHCi> data Foo = Foo { bar :: !Int, baz :: String } deriving Show
```

`bar` is a strict field, while `baz` is non-strict. To begin with, let's forget `baz`:

```
GHCi> x = Foo { bar = 3 }

<interactive>:49:5: warning: [-Wmissing-fields]
    * Fields of `Foo' not initialised: baz
    * In the expression: Foo {bar = 3}
      In an equation for `x': x = Foo {bar = 3}
```

We get a warning, but `x` is constructed. (Note the warning gets printed by default in GHCi when using `stack ghci`. You might have to use `:set -Wall` to see it in plain GHCi; I'm not entirely sure.) Trying to use the `baz` in `x` naturally gets us in trouble...

```
GHCi> x
Foo {bar = 3, baz = "*** Exception: <interactive>:49:5-19: Missing field in record construction baz
```

... though we can reach `bar` just fine:

```
GHCi> bar x
3
```

If we forget `bar`, though, we can't even construct the value to begin with:

```
GHCi> y = Foo { baz = "glub" }

<interactive>:51:5: error:
    * Constructor `Foo' does not have the required strict field(s): bar
    * In the expression: Foo {baz = "glub"}
      In an equation for `y': y = Foo {baz = "glub"}
GHCi> y

<interactive>:53:1: error: Variable not in scope: y
```